# Java: Got Jersey's ContainerException when receiving formdata, but fine when received raw JSON data

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, jooby, killbill

I'm currently working on a plugin for Killbill, using Jooby for developing the servlet. The servlet will receive a notification from payment gateway and process the update into internal Killbill system

```
@Singleton
public class NotificationServlet {

    private final InvoiceApi invoiceApi;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotificationServlet .class);

    @Inject
    public NotificationServlet() {
        // initiate InvoiceApi
        this.invoiceApi = new InvoiceApi(new KillBillHttpClient()); 
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/notify")
    public Result notify(@Body String body) throws KillBillClientException {
        logger.info(body);
        JSONObject dataJson = new JSONObject(body);
        if (dataJson.getString("status_code").equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            String referenceId = dataJson.getString("reference_id");
            String[] referenceIdArray = referenceId.split("\\|");
            String apiKey = referenceIdArray[0];
            String apiSecret = referenceIdArray[1];
            String accountId = referenceIdArray[2];
            String invoiceId = referenceIdArray[3];
            String amount = referenceIdArray[4];

            InvoicePayment invoicePayment = new InvoicePayment();
            invoicePayment.setPurchasedAmount(new BigDecimal(amount));
            invoicePayment.setAccountId(UUID.fromString(accountId));
            invoicePayment.setTargetInvoiceId(UUID.fromString(invoiceId));

            RequestOptions requestOptions = RequestOptions.builder()
                                                          .withCreatedBy("createdBy")
                                                          .withReason("reason")
                                                          .withComment("comment")
                                                          .withQueryParams(ArrayListMultimap.create())
                                                          .withTenantApiKey(apiKey)
                                                          .withTenantApiSecret(apiSecret)
                                                          .build();

            InvoicePayment result = invoiceApi.createInstantPayment(UUID.fromString(invoiceId),
                                                                    invoicePayment,
                                                                    true,
                                                                    null,
                                                                    null,
                                                                    requestOptions);
        }

        return Results.with("", Status.OK)
                      .type(MediaType.json);
    }
```

When I tested this servlet using Postman, the servlet works fine. But when I tested this with the payment gateway, I got Jersey's ContainerException

```
2022-04-07T16:08:07,423+0000 lvl='ERROR', log='[default]', th='catalina-exec-10', xff='', rId='', tok='', aRId='', tRId='', Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed] with root cause
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:367)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:152)
        at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:109)
        at org.killbill.billing.jaxrs.resources.PluginResource.createInputStream(PluginResource.java:247)
        at org.killbill.billing.jaxrs.resources.PluginResource.serviceViaOSGIPlugin(PluginResource.java:185)
        at org.killbill.billing.jaxrs.resources.PluginResource.doFormPOST(PluginResource.java:140)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:475)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:397)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:255)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:234)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:366)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:319)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:290)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:280)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:184)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:89)
        at org.killbill.billing.server.security.TenantFilter.handleAuthenticationError(TenantFilter.java:120)
        at org.killbill.billing.server.security.TenantFilter.doFilter(TenantFilter.java:89)
        at org.killbill.billing.server.filters.ResponseCorsFilter.doFilter(ResponseCorsFilter.java:75)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.helpers.MDCInsertingServletFilter.doFilter(MDCInsertingServletFilter.java:49)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:121)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:133)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.shiro.guice.web.SimpleFilterChain.doFilter(SimpleFilterChain.java:44)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.apache.shiro.guice.web.SimpleFilterChain.doFilter(SimpleFilterChain.java:41)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.apache.shiro.guice.web.SimpleFilterChain.doFilter(SimpleFilterChain.java:41)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:544)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:616)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1626)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I'm suspecting it might be because different type of body being sent, since I tested with Postman using raw data in JSON format meanwhile the gateway is sending x-www-form-urlencoded. I noticed this since there's a warning before this error appeared

```
2022-04-07T16:08:01,477+0000 lvl='WARN', log='WebComponent', th='catalina-exec-9', xff='', rId='', tok='', aRId='', tRId='', 
A servlet request to the URI http://path/to/my/notify-servlet contains form parameters in 
the request body but the request body has been consumed by the servlet or a servlet filter 
accessing the request parameters. Only resource methods using @FormParam will work as 
expected. Resource methods consuming the request body by other means will not work as expected.
```

I've tried adjusting the method according to [Jooby's docs on form submission](https://jooby.io/v1/doc/#request-form-submit), but the issue still persists. So is the issue still in Jooby or it's in Jersey?

Comment: Well yeah, if you know the gateway is going to send you form-urlencoded data, why are trying to use JSON? Have you tried using `@FormParam` like the warning suggests?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha i did try using `@FormParam` from Jersey, but the error (and the warning) still persisted

Comment: Yea so I've never used Jooby, but after looking at the documentation and starter projects, it doesn't use Jersey and the annotations they use are not JAX-RS annotations (`javax.rs.ws`), they are they're own annotations. See [the starter projects](https://github.com/search?q=topic%3Astarter+org%3Ajooby-project&type=Repositories)

Comment: So I'm not really sure how it's supposed to work. I would just look at their starter projects and see how your differs.